# PHP inside PHP problems

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I used conditional tags for Wordpress to customize the information output in the sidebar.

I used this:

```
<?php if is_home(); {

echo 'blah blah...' 

} else {

echo '<?php $myQuery = new WP_Query(\'showposts=3\');
      while ($myQuery->have_posts()) : $myQuery->the_post(); ?>'
<?php endwhile; ?>

} ?>
```

Now I always get "have_posts()) : $myQuery->the_post(); ?>" as text output in my sidebar,
so the $myquery part seems to cause problems, can anyone please help me find the mistake?

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit: Explanation
I want the sidebar to ouput other information on the blog index page (is_home). On all other pages except the blog index page, the last three posts should be displayed. That's why I used that WP_Query stuff

Comment: If you have it echo PHP code, it will echo PHP code, not execute it.

Comment: It almost ever not useful to output PHP-code inside a PHP script. Please explain, what exactly should be done.

Comment: escape slashes do not get parsed inside single quotes, that's the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
<?php if is_home(); {

echo 'blah blah...' 

} else {

    $myQuery = new WP_Query('showposts=3');
    while ($myQuery->have_posts()){
        $myQuery->the_post();
    }

} ?>
```

An `echo`(1) is used to output a string, it won't execute code. I'd recommend you look up every new function you encounter in the PHP manual(2) and if you can't find it there it's probably a WordPress specific function which you can look up in the WordPress Codex(3)

1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/
3. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/

Comment: Excuse me, I am new to PHP: so the problem simply was placing echo before the myQuery part? Seems very legit. I guess I have been blind.

Comment: Exactly and the opening PHP tags of course, they shouldn't be there as well because you already started with `<?php` (this means PHP code is following)